# Extracting data from one pandas dataframe and recording this data in the other dataframe, without merging/joining dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

How can I iterate through rows in column of one dataframe df1 and use IF STATEMENT (or other functions) to populate results in another dataframe df2? Or what other pandas dataframe operations I can do? I that possible?
I don't want to merge/join both dataframes, maybe only temporarily, but as a result I need df1.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'supplier': \['Interiors 365', 'Smart Builders', 'Architects Ltd', 'Builders Limited', 'Demolition Company'\]})
```

I am adding 2 empty columns do df1:

```
df1.insert(1, column = 'new_client', value = '')
df1.insert(2, column = 'buyer', value = '')
```

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VATTz.png)

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'company_name': ['Smart Builders', 'Architects Ltd', 'London Construction', 'Builders Limited', 'Demolition Company', 'Brighton Scaffolding'],
                    'status': ['Purchased', 'Registered', 'Registered', 'Registered', 'Purchased', 'Purchased']},
                    columns = ['company_name', 'status'])
```

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkrfV.png)

This is what I want to achieve:

I want to check in `df1` if for a given company (eg `'Architects Ltd'`) they registered or bought a product, and I want to save the result (`'Yes'`) in relevant cell (in row `'Architects Ltd'`, column `'new_client'` or `'buyer'`).

**My logic is:**

If a company name in `df2['company_name]` is the same as `df1['supplier'] AND if df2['status'] = 'Purchased'`, then put `'Yes'` in relevant cell in `df1['buyer']`.

If a company name in `df2['company_name]` is the same as `df1['supplier'] AND if df2['status'] = 'Registered'`, then put `'Yes'` in relevant cell in `df1['new_client']`.

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
#This doesn't check if the company name is the same 
df1.loc[df2['status'] == 'Purchased', 'buyer'] = 'Yes' (df2['company_name'] and df1['supplier'])

df1.loc[df2['status'] == 'Purchased' & df2['company_name'] == df1['supplier'], 'buyer'] = 'Yes'
```

This returns error: `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are looking for [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
m = df1['supplier'].isin(df2['company_name'])
df1.loc[m & df2['status'].eq('Purchased'), 'buyer'] = 'Yes'
df1.loc[m & df2['status'].eq('Registered'), 'new_client'] = 'Yes'
print(df1)

# Output:
             supplier new_client buyer
0       Interiors 365                 
1      Smart Builders        Yes      
2      Architects Ltd        Yes      
3    Builders Limited        Yes      
4  Demolition Company              Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `[pandas.DataFrame.apply][1]` as well.
Here is a code snippet to apply your conditions onto dataframe.

```
# In[6]:


import pandas as pd


# In[7]:


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'supplier': ['Interiors 365', 'Smart Builders', 'Architects Ltd', 'Builders Limited', 'Demolition Company']})
df1.insert(1, column = 'new_client', value = '')
df1.insert(2, column = 'buyer', value = '')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'company_name': ['Smart Builders', 'Architects Ltd', 'London Construction', 'Builders Limited', 'Demolition Company', 'Brighton Scaffolding'],
                    'status': ['Purchased', 'Registered', 'Registered', 'Registered', 'Purchased', 'Purchased']},
                    columns = ['company_name', 'status'])


# In[8]:


def is_new_client(row):
    supplier = row['supplier']
    registered = df2[(df2['company_name'] == supplier) & (df2['status'] == 'Registered')].shape[0] > 0
    if registered:
        df1.loc[df1['supplier'] == supplier, 'new_client'] = 'Yes'

df1.apply(is_new_client, axis=1)


# In[9]:


print(df1)


# In[10]:


def is_buyer(row):
    supplier = row['supplier']
    purchased = df2[(df2['company_name'] == supplier) & (df2['status'] == 'Purchased')].shape[0] > 0
    if purchased:
        df1.loc[df1['supplier'] == supplier, 'buyer'] = 'Yes'

df1.apply(is_buyer, axis=1)


# In[11]:


print(df1)


# In[ ]:
```

Output

```
             supplier new_client buyer
0       Interiors 365                 
1      Smart Builders              Yes
2      Architects Ltd        Yes      
3    Builders Limited        Yes      
4  Demolition Company              Yes
```